# Add AMPL to SCITE editor and add GLPK solver

Tags: programming-languages, solver, ampl, scite, mathprog

Can someone explain me step by step how to add AMPL to SCITE editor and add GLPK solver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find instructions on how to use AMPL with SCITE and GLPK [here](http://archive.ite.journal.informs.org/Vol7No1/LeeRaffensperger/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are windows userr, get GUSEK - SciTE editor and it is designed to work GMPL/MathProg (GMPL). MathProg is subset of AMPL.  GUSEK uses GLPK as solver.

http://gusek.sourceforge.net/gusek.html

You can also use GLPK Lab for Windows.

http://glpklabw.sourceforge.net/

GLPK/MathProg is FOSS software -- FREE.

Linux users, just copy the some of the files from GLPK lab or GUSEK to gtk SciTE.